# Are 0-Level Spell Scars Free?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

I am playing Pathfinder and I have a Rogue 7 Magus 3 build. I have a Magus Arcana called Spell Scars which says I can add a total of 18 level spells (adding spells is similar to a Scribe Scroll feat). Can I add 0 level spells for free?

Answer (score 2):

Spell Scars uses the same item pricing guidelines as scrolls, which, as per Pathfinder's [Item Creation](https://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html) rules:

> **Spell Level**: A 0-level spell is half the value of a 1st-level spell for determining price.

Comment: Note that while they are *priced* as 1/2 level spells, they still count as 0 level spells in terms of space (i.e. you can have any number of them without it adding up to 18)

Answer (score 0):

**Probably not**

The Spell scar Arcana doesn't explain how it deals with space for 0th level spells, so I'm going to extrapolate that it is similar to how much space a 0th level spell takes up in a spellbook .

> **Space in the Spellbook:** A spell takes up one page of the spellbook per
>   spell level. Even a 0-level spell (cantrip) takes one page. A
>   spellbook has 100 pages.

Given that a 0th level spell takes up one page of a spellbook, one can probably assume that a 0th level spell scar takes up the equivalent amount of space on your skin as a first level spell scar.

This is how I would rule as GM at least.